# Android instantly reboots on incoming call

Tags: calls, reboot, soft-reboot

I can't even see the caller ID on the screen, when my phone soft reboots. It began when I did factory reset 2 days ago. No software installed besides system default apps.

Phone: BLU Life One X (2016) rooted with Android Lollipop (5.1)

This is what I get from logcat when there's incoming call.

```
E/ActivityThread(  538): Service com.google.android.gms.car.CarService has leaked ServiceConnection fmj@16cdbf61 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread(  538): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.car.CarService has leaked ServiceConnection fmj@16cdbf61 that was originally bound here
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1116)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1010)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1895)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1878)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:539)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at ivw.a(:com.google.android.gms:120)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at ivw.a(:com.google.android.gms:137)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at fmj.h(:com.google.android.gms:76)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at fmj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:64)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at fpn.i(:com.google.android.gms:551)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at com.google.android.gms.car.CarChimeraService.onBind(:com.google.android.gms:165)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at com.google.android.chimera.container.ServiceProxy.onBind(:com.google.android.gms:165)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3028)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:178)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
E/ActivityThread(  538):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
E/AALService(  298): [ERROR] Kernel does not support AAL, please enable CONFIG_MTK_AAL_SUPPORT in kconfig.
E/MPlugin (30062): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
E/ActivityThread(30062): Failed to find provider info for com.tinno.mobilesafe
E/ActivityThread(30062): Failed to find provider info for com.tinno.mobilesafe
E/GesturePhoneService(30850): onCallStateChanged, bUpsetSilentOn=false bUpsetSpeakerOn=false bProxAnswerOn=false
E/MPlugin (30062): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.audioprofile.IAudioProfileExtension$IDefaultProfileStatesGetter



E/AndroidRuntime(30062): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30062): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:470)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:460)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:432)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Ringer.startRingingOrCallWaiting(Ringer.java:326)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Ringer.updateRinging(Ringer.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Ringer.onForegroundCallChanged(Ringer.java:187)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.CallsManager.updateForegroundCall(CallsManager.java:1784)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.CallsManager.updateCallsManagerState(CallsManager.java:1810)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.CallsManager.addCall(CallsManager.java:1609)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.CallsManager.onSuccessfulIncomingCall(CallsManager.java:330)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Call.processDirectToVoicemail(Call.java:830)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Call.setCallerInfo(Call.java:1418)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Call.access$000(Call.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.telecom.Call$1.onQueryComplete(Call.java:178)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.internal.telephony.CallerInfoAsyncQuery$CallerInfoAsyncQueryHandler.onQueryComplete(CallerInfoAsyncQuery.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:344)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
E/AndroidRuntime(30062):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
E/ActivityThread(  578): Failed to find provider info for settings
```

Also the call is not being logged to missed calls history.

I have already tried to

- Factory reset (from settings)
- Hard reset (from recovery)
- Change SIM card

Comment: what do you do in recovery "factory reset"? do you only reset data or wipe cache and dalvik cache also? if you don't, try doing it also. plus if you are using custom rom, check its forums if someone else got same error

Comment: I wiped all kind of caches including dalvik. Unfortunately, I got AOSP unmodified, couldn't find any occurrences of this kind of errors.

Comment: Does the device ship with some CallerID software? I remember a similar case from the past having comparable results. Disabling the CallerID stuff cured it. Check the settings of your telephony app if you can find something like that. If it's there, simply disable it (at least the "internet lookup" parts, i.e. online phone book lookups: the error message starting with `UriParse` seems to suggest as much).

Comment: @Izzy thanks for reply. I can't find any option to disable the caller id information. The thing is that calling worked perfectly few weeks ago before the factory reset. I have no idea how can factory reset ruin the calling feature.

Comment: Sorry to read that. Unfortunately I don't remember the details – just that it was some "external service" (some Yellow Pages or the like) one needed to untick.

Comment: Here's the solution, if anyone encounters the same problem. It's because of the ringtone. The URI of the ringtone is always null (Thanks BLU!) and code is trying to resolve it with no success (nullpointerexception). The solution right now is to set phone to Vibrate mode. This is the only way to fix the problem. I'll try to decompile the dialer app and fix the error.

Comment: does changing ring tone solve problem? if yes then please post it as an answer so that it can help others too. but I still don't understand how error can be in com.google.android.gms.car.CarService. i searched this service belongs to Google auto. do you have any auto app installed? and if this is manufacturing defect then all BLU phones should have it not just yours.

Comment: Just in case, the settings app is crashing when trying to change the ringtone. Already posted the solution as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was not obvious. It's because of the corrupted telecom.service (dialer) app. BLOX 2016 always had issues with ringtones, but I guess they completely ruined it in some of their updates. The only way to get around is to install TWRP and flash a new ROM backup. You can find those on XDA forums BLU Life One X thread.

The other solution is to set the phone to Vibrate mode and never change it back to ringer.